What are the possible userspace addresses an ARM MacOS Machine?
Is there a virtual memory map for MacOS on Arm (specifically Apple Silicon, specifically M1), which states which virtual addresses could be valid user space addresses which could be returned by mmap/malloc? (And if for some reason there are valid addresses which couldn't come from mmap, what are they?).
